# Brother MFC scanner not recognized on one computer

Tags: mac, ventura, scanning

I have multiple Macs at home. I have a Brother MFC L8850CDW. On all the computers except for one, this printer is recognized as a scanner by Apple's Brother print driver. I can't figure out why this computer can print but won't recognize the scanning functionality. Things I've tried (and I'll focus on two computers that are sitting next to each other side by side):

- Updating Brother firmware didn't help.
- Two Apple Silicon laptops, same OS (latest ventura os), same AirPrint driver, but only one recognizes the scanning functionality.
- On the laptop that doesn't recognize the scanner, resetting the print system didn't help.
- Not using Bonjour (and using IP) didn't help.
- Restarting computers or printer didn't help.

I'm out of ideas. These two computers are nearly identical (and software-wise, are completely identical), but one will scan and the other won't!

Comment: First, you have to treat it as two separate devices - a scanner and a printer.  A print driver won’t scan and vice versa.  Try uninstalling the driver completely, then reinstalling.  Next, assuming you can “talk” to the printer, see if you can install the scanner manually.

Comment: Hmmm, I've never had to treat them as two separate devices. On all the other computers, I "Add Printer" in preferences and it detects both functions of the device. How do I even install the scanner after the printer is already added in the "Pinrters & Scanners" preference pane?

Comment: That driver package just installs both drivers.  There are [many questions here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=Brother+scanner) with very similar issues to yours.  The fact one part works (printer) and the other doesn’t (scanner) proves this.  A driver can’t work “half way”